# Text search based on relevance in Django by matching relevanct data to each individual items in object

Tags: django, relevance, text-search

```
class Org(models.Model):
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email_id = models.EmailField()
    incorporation_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.org_name
```

Data at hand org_name, name, phone, email_id, incorporation_date... How can I use the data I have to compare with the data in model and display results based on relevance.

Example:

```
Apple, Steve, 000-000-0000, steveo@apple.com, 1979
```

I should be able to compare Apple with data in org_name, Steve in name etc.., and display the rows which has the match and in descending order of relevance using DJANGO!

Comment: Complex and presumably weighted ranking like that is usually best left to Solr or another specialized search process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cook something up using the SQL, but the proper solution for this is using a full-text search engine. [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) is a great package that will let you solve this quickly.

Comment: Haystack with Solr is an option but the above query will be used by only one user and hardly once in a month, I am assuming haystack and solr for this requirement is little too much of work.

Comment: @SantoshSKumar no need to use Solr - you can use Haystack with Whoosh which doesn't require any separate setup and should be easy to get started with.